# Is it possible to synchronize coordinate system between 2 devices in Unity with ARCore?

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore, unity3d-unet

I work with ARCore in Unity and would like to know how I can synchronize coordinate system between 2 devices with help Network Manager. Maybe somebody knows if it is possible/impossible. Thanks.

Comment: You’d have to add an extra layer of recognition. Easy way would be to use a marker that would set the origin of the scene so both system are in sync.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Cloud Anchors](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity/cloud-anchors/cloud-anchors-quickstart-unity-android) is probably the most reliable way of coordinating multiple viewers in the same AR Scene.

The [Cloud Anchors Sample](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk/tree/master/Assets/GoogleARCore/Examples/CloudAnchor) uses the Unity networking to share information.